# Seting proper separator for sql insert

Tags: java, str-replace

I got the app, that ask the user for a float value. The thing is he can use a "," instead "."

Sure I can swap them with for loop but there might be some method for that already, is it?

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in your java code: `mystring.replace(',', '.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (s being the input string):

```
s = s.replace(',','.');
```

For more detailed info on what you can do with basic Java Strings, check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29).

Answer (score 1):

For replacing on character in another you can do it using the [replace(char,char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method like this: `value.replace(',','.')`

If the mater is for SQL, then please specify which database you are targeting.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the locale which decimal (',' or '.' ) will be used.

It is bad practice to assume a locle and doing a workaround with replace. You should rather use prepared statements and set the arguments with the correct type.